# Gridview with clickable dynamic images

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which loads images in a column depending on the value of another column.
I want the image to be clickable and show the picture in full width
The code to load the image is here

```
        Protected Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

        Dim img As Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgID")
        Dim NewSearch As String = ""

        Dim mFile As String = ""
        Dim MsPLIT As Array

        NewSearch = e.Row.Cells(0).Text 'first column value

        MsPLIT = Split(NewSearch, "+")
        mFile = MsPLIT(0)

        img.ImageUrl = mFile & ".jpg"            
    End If
    End Sub
```

I tried to insert a hyperlink and the image but I don't know how to send the URL to the image file.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="?" runat="server">
         <asp:Image ID="imgID" runat="server" Width="100" Height="100" />
     </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use imagebutton instead:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="Img1" ImageUrl="" ...
```

No need for `navigateurl`, just use the `imageurl` in the `click` event handler to redirect to the `imageurl`.

In your code-behind:

```
Private Sub Img1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles Img1.Click
    Response.Redirect(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).ImageUrl)
End Sub
```

Because you are using the GridView, you need to do a `findcontrol`. You get the idea.

Comment: OK I did it, but now I want to open the picture in the same window not in a new with javascript. where to write the code?

Comment: Great @RubyKousinovali ! Here we are giving the image path as the url to open in a new page. In order to open in the same page, you will have to resort to using jQuery/Javascript. Read up on jQuery Dialog or LightBox.